# Why query executes fast with variable?

Tags: mysql, variables, indexing

Why This with @_id:= executes much faster than without this variable? I wanna put this query un a view, and I can't put variables In views, but without this... query terminated with timeout, and with this variable in less then 1sec

```sql
select vsa.idSimulado, 
       vsa.RA, 
       db.disciplina ,
       count(idSimuladoQuestao) as questoes, 
       count(if(sq.gabarito = sra.resposta ,1, NULL)) as acertos 
from SimuladoRespostaAluno sra
inner join ( select idSimuladoQuestao, 
                    fkSimulado, 
                    gabarito, 
                    @_id := getBaseDisciplina(fkDisciplina) as idDisciplinaBase 
             from SimuladoQuestao ) sq on sra.fkSimuladoQuestao = sq.idSimuladoQuestao
inner join Disciplina db on db.idDisciplina = idDisciplinaBase
inner join vwsimuladoaluno vsa on vsa.idSimulado = sq.fkSimulado and vsa.RA = sra.fkAluno 
group by vsa.idSimulado, 
         vsa.RA, 
         db.disciplina;
```

Explain output WITHOUT Variable

```
'1','SIMPLE','sa',NULL,'ALL','SimuladoAluno_fkSimulados_idx',NULL,NULL,NULL,'548','100.00','Using temporary; Using filesort'
'1','SIMPLE','s',NULL,'eq_ref','PRIMARY','PRIMARY','4','oficina_simulados.sa.fkSimulado','1','100.00','Using index'
'1','SIMPLE','a',NULL,'eq_ref','PRIMARY','PRIMARY','62','func','1','100.00','Using where; Using index'
'1','SIMPLE','SimuladoQuestao',NULL,'ref','PRIMARY,SimuladoQuestao_fkSimulado_idx','SimuladoQuestao_fkSimulado_idx','4','oficina_simulados.sa.fkSimulado','70','100.00',NULL
'1','SIMPLE','sra',NULL,'ref','SimuladoRepostaAluno_fkSimulado_idx','SimuladoRepostaAluno_fkSimulado_idx','4','oficina_simulados.SimuladoQuestao.idSimuladoQuestao','71','10.00','Using where'
'1','SIMPLE','db',NULL,'ALL',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'1552','10.00','Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)'
```

Explain output WITH Variable

```
'1','PRIMARY','<derived2>',NULL,'ALL',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'638','100.00','Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort'
'1','PRIMARY','db',NULL,'eq_ref','PRIMARY','PRIMARY','4','sq.idDisciplinaBase','1','100.00','Using where'
'1','PRIMARY','sra',NULL,'ref','SimuladoRepostaAluno_fkSimulado_idx','SimuladoRepostaAluno_fkSimulado_idx','4','sq.idSimuladoQuestao','71','100.00',NULL
'1','PRIMARY','<derived3>',NULL,'ref','<auto_key0>','<auto_key0>','66','sq.fkSimulado,oficina_simulados.sra.fkAluno','10','100.00',NULL
'3','DERIVED','s',NULL,'ALL','PRIMARY',NULL,NULL,NULL,'8','100.00',NULL
'3','DERIVED','sa',NULL,'ref','SimuladoAluno_fkSimulados_idx','SimuladoAluno_fkSimulados_idx','4','oficina_simulados.s.idSimulado','78','100.00',NULL
'3','DERIVED','a',NULL,'eq_ref','PRIMARY','PRIMARY','62','func','1','100.00','Using where'
'2','DERIVED','SimuladoQuestao',NULL,'ALL',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'638','100.00',NULL
```

Comment: I can't think of any reason why that should affect the performance.

Comment: Can you show the output of `EXPLAIN` of the two versions of the query?

Comment: The variable might be affecting the way that it optimizes calling the `getBaseDisciplina()` function.

Comment: @Barmar I edit the posts with EXPLAIN.. the variable appear to create a index I don't understand just how.... I wanna know if is possible to create this index effect without variable... to put this on one view... and see if I can use this trick in others searches

Comment: There might be something you can do with `FORCE INDEX`.

Comment: I see no table alias named "sa"??  Both Explains show such.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.